# Close app when webdriver is closed

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

How can I close my app when a user closes the webdriver? Right now I am using:

```
 catch (InvalidOperationException)
 {
     App.Current.MainWindow.Close();
 }
```

But this only closes the app when the user tries to do something after the webdriver is closed, can I close my app right after the webdriver?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

try this:
driver.quit()
regards.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Usually it's good practice to add in a little explanation along with your answer.